# MSSQL- Raiserror will display error at right time but will not stop insertion

Tags: sql-server, raiserror

I'm currently building a stored procedure in MSSQL to insert credit cards into my database.

I have a check to see if the CC is all digits `[0-9]` in an `IF` statement and a `RAISERROR` when it is not all digits `[0-9]`.

The problem is that the `RAISERROR` is catching the mistakes and displaying the error message on the webpage but it still inserts the bad data into my table.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
-- Checking to see that @CC is composed of number [0-9]

declare @error_message9 varchar(225)

if not(@CC like '%[0-9]%+$')
    Begin
        set @error_Message9 = 'Error[9]: [ ' + @CC + ' ] is not a vaild number. CC must contain all numbers [0-9]'
        raiserror(@error_Message9, 16, 1)
    End
```

Comment: You should be using a client-side programming language for form validation, not the database.

Comment: Are you sure that expression is doing what you're expecting? T-SQL doesn't directly support regular expressions, but that 'like' expression sure looks like one. See if a string like 'A5A+$' passes. Also, for a newer app, consider using THROW rather than RAISERROR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a return statement after raiserror.

```
if not(@CC like '%[0-9]%+$')
    Begin
        set @error_Message9 = 'Error[9]: [ ' + @CC + ' ] is not a vaild number. CC must contain all numbers [0-9]'
        raiserror(@error_Message9, 16, 1)
        return 
    End
```

Comment: Welcome, please accept the answer (& upvote if you wish) if it solved your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL 2012 or above, I would actually use throw instead of raiserror.  Throw will cause the statement batch to terminate.

http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/